# Clear cookies on first load

Tags: asp.net, cookies

I want application to clear cookie for every user on first site load after publishing. The matter is, cookies can store much information, that becomes non-actual after publishing, but is still in use. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing that I used to do is set some unique string in the cookie.

Lets say *blah blah blah* or whatever. And you can keep the same string in the web.config file as well.

When the cookie is read, it checks whether the unique string in the cookie matches the string in the web.config file.

If it is, you simply proceed and if it's not, you discard the cookie.

So if you simply change the string in the web.config file, next time a user tries to log in, the cookie will be discarded.

Comment: Good idea, thanks. But in my case, cookies are used by another third-party component and I can't affect it.

Comment: So you have to keep track somehow that the cookie is expired. A shorter expiry date for the cookie?